# ¿Como filtrar un array por medio de sus claves, contenidas en otro array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

De ante mano gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios.

Quiero lograr lo siguiente tengo dos arrays con clave y valor el primero es un array con varios valores y el segundo un array de arrays con varios valores, lo que intento lograr es conservar las keys y valor de mi primer array cuyo keys coincidan con la key "value" de mi segundo array.
Ingreso código para hacerme entender mejor:

```
$array1 = [
    "id" => 13,
    "name" => "MAURO",
    "code" => "2903",
    "lastname" => "GARCIA",
    "email" => "angel.infotec@gmail.mx",
    "second_lastname" => "VARELA",
    "rfc" => "GAVM540516",
    "curp" => "GAVM540516HJCRRR02",
    "nss" => "70707070707",
];
$array2 =
[
    [
       "id" => 14,
        "name" => "rfc",
        "isActive" => true,
        "value" => "rfc",
    ],  
    [
    "id" => 15,
    "name" => "numero de empleado",
    "isActive" => true,
    "value" => "code",
    ],
];
```

Del array1 quiero conservar los valores cuyo key coincidan con el valor de la key value de mi segundo array es decir un resultado como este:

```
$resultado = [
 "rfc" => "GAVM540516",
 "code" => "2903"
];
```

Había logrado algo similar a esto en el escenario que mi array2 sea un array simple comparto código:

```
$array1 = [
    "id" => 13,
    "name" => "MAURO",
    "code" => "2903",
    "lastname" => "GARCIA",
    "email" => "angel.infotec@gmail.mx",
    "second_lastname" => "VARELA",
    "rfc" => "GAVM540516",
    "curp" => "GAVM540516HJCRRR02",
    "nss" => "70707070707",
];
$array2= ["rfc","code"];

var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2)));
```

Esto funciona el problema que tengo ahora es que mi array dos ahora es un array de arrays.
Gracias de nuevo por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que buscas con la funcion `array_key_exists()` asi:

```
$array1 = [
    "id" => 13,
    "name" => "MAURO",
    "code" => "2903",
    "lastname" => "GARCIA",
    "email" => "angel.infotec@gmail.mx",
    "second_lastname" => "VARELA",
    "rfc" => "GAVM540516",
    "curp" => "GAVM540516HJCRRR02",
    "nss" => "70707070707",
];
$array2 =
[
    [
       "id" => 14,
        "name" => "rfc",
        "isActive" => true,
        "value" => "rfc",
    ],  
    [
    "id" => 15,
    "name" => "numero de empleado",
    "isActive" => true,
    "value" => "code",
    ],
];
$resultado = array();
foreach($array2 as $item) {
  if (array_key_exists($item['value'], $array1)) {
    $resultado[$item['value']] = $array1[$item['value']];
  }
}
var_dump($resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola comparto como solucione mi problema aunque creo que habrá otra forma más limpia de poder resolverlo, sigo abierto a sus respuestas.

Comparto mi solución:

```
<?php
$array1 = [
    "id" => 13,
    "name" => "MAURO",
    "code" => "2903",
    "lastname" => "GARCIA",
    "email" => "angel.infotec@gmail.mx",
    "second_lastname" => "VARELA",
    "rfc" => "GAVM540516",
    "curp" => "GAVM540516HJCRRR02",
    "nss" => "70707070707",
];
$array2 =
[
    [
       "id" => 14,
        "name" => "rfc",
        "isActive" => true,
        "value" => "rfc",
    ],  
    [
    "id" => 15,
    "name" => "numero de empleado",
    "isActive" => true,
    "value" => "code",
    ],
];

$array3= [];


foreach ($array2 as $item) {
    array_push($array3, $item['value']);
}

$config = array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array3));
var_dump($config);

?>
```